# When does the limit of a sum become an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration

In many maths and physics texts and courses, I've been told in many cases that the limit of a sum becomes an integral, i.e. (very roughly):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^n f(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x) dx$$

However I know that this equation can't be true in every case, otherwise series would not exist. So I'd like to ask: what characteristics does $f(x)$ have for the above equation to be true?

**More details:**

Yesterday I had to resolve a series like this:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n}$$

This comes from a real-life problem. I decided to find the value of that limit using the following integral:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} dx$$

The reasons why I decided to go with the integral are two: habit and because I needed the sum to be continuous (meaning: every value summed must be infinitesimal). Also, I've always been told that sums are for discrete values, integrals are for continuous/infinitesimal ones.

The problem is that I do not have a mathematical justification for that. And while testing shows that the result matches reality, I don't know whether it is mathematically correct, or it is just a coincidence. So I asked myself: why should my limit be an integral and not a series?

I decided to calculate first the expression of $\sum_{x=0}^n (1-e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n}$ (which is $1 - e^{1/n+1}$) and afterwards the limit for $n$ to infinity ($1  - e$). The result is the same of the integral, and I'm a bit surprised by that.

The reason why I'm surprised can be explained looking at the picture on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/247252/99513). My sum is not an area, however it it were, I'd know for sure that what I need is the picture on the left rather than the one on the right (being a real-life problem, I know in advance the nature of the operands I'm dealing with).

What's going on here? Which of the following equations is the most correct?

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} dx \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} = \sum_{x=0}^n (1-e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n}
$$

What I'm really interested in knowing: when do I need to transform a limit of a sum into an integral? And: does it happens every time that, when a limit of a sum is equal to an integral, the corresponding series have the same result?

Comment: I don't know if there is a more general solution, but if the sum is of the form of an upper or lower sum for a Riemann integrable function, then the limit converges to the integral of the corresponding function.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I suspected that Riemann integrals where the key here, however I failed at finding the definition of "sum of the form of an upper or lower sum for a Riemann integrable function". Or better: everything I found on the web did not look like my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look up the definition of the Riemann integral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums), you will find that it is the limit of a sequence of sums. The same holds for the Lebesgue integral.

**Update**
Now I looked properly at the remainder of your question.
If you think about your sum, you are actually computing an integral over [0,1], approximated by points $x/n$ for $x = 0, ..., n$.

Also note that, for large $n$, $(1-e^{1/n}) \approx -1/n$.
So let's rewrite
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=0}^n (1-e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} & \approx - \sum_{x=0}^n e^{1-x/n} \frac 1 n 
\approx - \int_0^1 e^{1-\xi} \ d \xi = 1 - e
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's ( any way, check the Riemann stuff… )
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^n (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-x)/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \color{#ff0000}{n}\int_0^\color{#ff0000}{1} (1 - e^{1/n}) e^{(n-\color{#ff0000}{n}x)/n} dx 
=
{\rm e}\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 - e^{1/n} \over 1/n}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm e}^{-x}\,{\rm d}x
\\&=
{\rm e}\left(-1\right)\left(-{\rm e} + 1\right)
=
{\rm e}\left({\rm e} - 1\right)
\end{align}