# What is easiest way to prove that $\sqrt 8/2$ is equal to $\sqrt 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the most easy way I can prove $\sqrt 8/2$ is equal to $\sqrt 2$

I have done $(\sqrt 8/2)^2$ but at the end it gives me $\pm \sqrt 2$ and not positive $\sqrt 2$ So how?

Comment: Nobody ever asks for the most difficult way.

Comment: Interesting! I also want most most of most difficult way

Comment: @WillJagy Out of curiosity, what _is_ the most difficult way? :)

Comment: The most difficult way is to find a polynomial that gives the same result for x=his two values. :) ok, just kidding, but 2sqrt2=sqrt8.

Comment: I think there is no such thing as the most difficult way. You can probably always overcomplicate a solution.

Comment: Quoted comment by me, in 2010: Latest paper, my co-author put in "but we will choose a more painful way, because there is nothing like pain for feeling alive" but the referee jumped on it. –  Will Jagy Apr 23 '10...... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22299/what-are-some-examples-of-colorful-language-in-serious-mathematics-papers

Comment: And a "simple" complicated solution would probably be to find a complex integral where the residue theorem would Yields $\sqrt{2} \pi i$ while a parametrisation of the curve would Yield $\frac{\sqrt{8}\pi i}{2}$....

Comment: According to the last line of the question, all that you really needed was a proof that $\sqrt 8/2$ is positive. Well, $\sqrt8$ is positive, and half of a positive number is still positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt 8 =\sqrt{4\cdot 2}=\sqrt4\cdot\sqrt2=2\sqrt2$$

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sqrt{8}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2\times4}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{4}}{2} = \dots$$

Comment: In the last one you can cancel the 2's, for $$  \frac{\sqrt{ }\times\sqrt{4}}{ }  $$

Comment: So we end up with $\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}$???

Comment: @WillJagy Hence we have $\frac{\sqrt{}\times\sqrt{4}}{}=\sqrt{2}$?  Ingeniuos!

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I actually did not think it through that far. I was just thinking of John's answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260656/cant-argue-with-success-looking-for-bad-math-that-gets-away-with-it/260662#260662  This one does seem to work out as well, which is pretty funny.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}\iff\sqrt{8}=\sqrt{2^2\cdot2}$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by the square root of 4 and divide by 2. It is the same thing as multiplying by 1.