# Two different results of calculation of the limit of $(2+4+\dots+2n)/n^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I would like to know where is the problem when i calculated those two limit with the following ways :
**method (1)**:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac { 2+4+6+\cdots 2n} {n²} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac {n(n+1)}{n²}  =1 $$( using arithmitic sequence sum ).

**Method (2)** : now by using operation over limit we get this:
{n²}$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac { 2+4+6+\cdots 2n} {n²} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac {2}{n²}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {4}{n²}+\cdots \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {2n}{n²}  =0+0+\cdots 0=0 $$ .

Then is there some one who show me where is the problem in second method ?
Thank you for any help

Comment: Is the denominator $n$ or $n^2$?

Comment: Method 2 is wrong. The summands are infinitely many.

Comment: How many terms are you adding here? $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac {2}{n²}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {4}{n²}+\cdots \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {2n}{n²}$$

Comment: This is the problem , mayeb the number of terms are unknown

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I think Bungo meant that question as a question for you to reflect on. It's really at the core of the issue. Read mvw's answer for clarification.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/261062/236182

Comment: Would you also agree $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\cdots+\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0+0+\cdots+0=0$$

Answer (score 3):

You are trying
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{n^2}
"=" \sum_{k=1}^n \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2k}{n^2}
"=" \sum_{k=1}^n \lim_{m \to\infty} \frac{2k}{m^2}
$$
but $n$ has to be constant within the summation scope. 
For the middle term it can not stay both fixed and be subject of a limit.
Only the first and last term are well defined (and different).

Answer (score -1):

in method 2 you are summing an infinite number of zeros: the result is undefined, not 0.

Comment: The problem occurs earlier than that; it's with mimicking "limit of sum is the sum of limits" in a situation when it doesn't apply.

Comment: but 0 for n times is 0

Comment: Yes! The mistake is realy there.

Comment: No, that's not a mistake at all. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 0=0$.

Comment: it's not 0 n times, its small amount n times, tending towards 0 infinite times.