# Finding value of integration with infinite limit

Tags: integration

Finding value of $\displaystyle \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x(e^{2x}+1)(e^x+1)} \, dx$

Attempt: Let $\displaystyle I = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x(e^{2x}+1)(e^x+1)} \, dx = 2\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x(e^{2x}+1)(e^x+1)} \, dx$

So $$I = 2\int^\infty_0 \bigg(\frac{1}{e^x+1}-\frac 1 {e^{2x}+1}\bigg)\frac 1 x \, dx = 2\int_0^\infty \frac 1 {(e^x+1)x} \, dx - 2\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(e^{2x}+1)x} \, dx$$

Could some help me how to solve it, thanks.

Comment: because function is even function

Comment: $\int_0^a\frac1{x(e^x+1)}\ dx$ does not converge.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Integral_representations

Comment: The given integral is convergent, at $x=0$ there is a hole in the graph. So the two separate integrals may not be convergent, somehow the results of their anti derivatives should produce something. I wonder if it can be done though...

Comment: Wow, that link is very cool!!!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I posted the wrong link twice. I'm not having a good day. :(

Comment: @imranfat It just got cooler ;)

Comment: @RandomVariable lol, I saw nothing.

Comment: If you leave the linear $x$ term out of the denominator, the answer to the integral remains unchanged: $ln2$. But the resulting integral is way easier to calculate. Conclusion: Whenever you deem an $x$ to be making an integral unnecessary difficult: So just omit it.

Comment: @imranfat xD don't give out such bad advice!  Naughty you.