# Understanding an intuitive explanation of the derivative of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

This question is related to this question here [Can't argue with success? Looking for "bad math" that "gets away with it"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260656/cant-argue-with-success-looking-for-bad-math-that-gets-away-with-it)
The question is about ways to get the right answer with incorrect logic/methods.

One of the answers with $104$ score by Hans Engler reads like this

> Here's another classical freshman calculus example:
>
> Find $\frac{d}{dx} x^x$.
>
> Alice says "this is like $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n−1}$, so the answer is $xx^{x−1}=x^x$." Bob says "no, this is like $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \log{a}⋅a^x$, so the answer is $\log{x}⋅x^x$." Charlie says "if you're not sure, just add the two terms, so you'll get partial credit".
>
> The answer $\frac{d}{dx} x^x= (1+\log x)x^x$ turns out to be correct.

Joriki in the comments of this answer states that

> That's not wrong; that's a perfectly valid method. You get the derivative of any expression with respect to x as the sums of all the derivatives with respect to the individual instances of x while holding all other instances constant.

I am having trouble making sense of his comment, this is what I think it means.

Imagine that the $x$s in $x^x$ were different. Let's call them $x_1$ and $x_2$. Thus, our expression becomes ${x_1}^{x_2}$. I believe his comment is saying that the rate of change of ${x_1}^{x_2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} {x_1}^{x_2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} {x_1}^{x_2}$. Each partial derivative evaluates the change in the quantity with respect to a different $x$ and sums them up while keeping the other $x$ constant, just like the comment says. However, I am not sure why this equality is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll spell out @joriki's logic. Define $f(u,\,v):=u^v,\,u:=x,\,v:=x$ so, by the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Case_of_f(g1(x),_..._,_gk(x))),$$\frac{df}{dx}=\color{red}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}}+\color{blue}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}}=\color{red}{vu^{v-1}}+\color{blue}{u^v\ln u}.$$Alice only used the red term, forgetting $dv/dx\ne0$; Bob only used the blue term, forgetting $du/dx\ne0$; Charlie used both. While the above calculation affords a more general "Alice, Bob, Charlie & Joriki" problem, [a subsection of the above link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Example:_arithmetic_operations) actually discusses this choice of $f$.