# "Too simple to be true"

Tags: big-list, fake-proofs

As indicates the title, this question is about "proofs" of *true* statements which are short and/or look elegant but are wrong.

I mean example like Cayley-Hamilton's theorem, which states that for a $n\times n$ matrix over $\Bbb C$, and $\chi$ its characteristic polynomial, then $\chi(A)=0$. The well-known fake proof consists of a substitution $\lambda=A$ in $\chi(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$, which is not allowed.

So, I think writing a big-list could be interesting, where each answer will contain:

- the statement;
- the fake proof;
- an explanation of the gap in the proof;
- if possible, a reference to a good proof.

Each one can concern any field of mathematics. It will be good to have an example in every field: real analysis, measure theory, etc...

Comment: The fake proof is easy to fix though: change the base field from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\overline{\mathbb{C}(x_{1,1}, \ldots, x_{n,n})}$...

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree, but it's not so simple to think about such a fixation when we believed we could replace a scalar by a matrix.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you give a reference? (I'm interested in the detailed proof. I'm not an algebraist.) Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same question as [Pseudo Proofs that are intuitively reasonable](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/123633/)? It seems that many of the answers there would qualify as answers to your question.

Comment: @Martin I've done a research and I didn't find it, and indeed it's related. However (it's my opinion, not necessarily true), the other thread gives "non rigorous" proofs, which are _not necessarily_ wrong.

Comment: The gap in the proof of Cayley-Hamilton is that "evaluation at $A$" would result in $\det(I \otimes A - A \otimes I )$, where $\otimes$ is the kronecker product, and the determinant is taken as an $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}[A]$, not as an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$. I'm sure the proof could be finished in this manner, but alas I don't see an easy method.

Comment: There is a whole book about that ranging over various fields of mathematics. Mathematical Fallacies, Flaws and Flimflam by Edward J. Barbeau. Love it! And for all of the "proofs", it takes care of the first three of your bullets.

Comment: [Is this related?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics-closed)

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo No, because I want _true statements_ with an attempt of proof which doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8814, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole book about that ranging over various fields of mathematics. [Mathematical Fallacies, Flaws and Flimflam by Edward J. Barbeau](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883855291). Love it! And for all of the "proofs", it takes care of the first three of your bullets.

Answer (score 20):

My favorite is the following:

Let $\pi$ be rational, and write $\pi = a/b$ in lowest term. Let $p \neq 2$ be a prime not dividing $a$. Then in $\Bbb{Q}_{p}$, we have

$$ 0 = \sin(pb\pi) = \sin(pa) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}(pa)^{2n+1} \equiv pa \ (\mathrm{mod} \ p^2), $$

which is absurd since $a \not\equiv 0$ mod $p$. Therefore $\pi$ is irrational.

The essential gap in this *too-good-to-be* a proof is that a $p$-adic power series may not converge to the same value as in the real field case, even the series consists of only rational terms. Thus the value of $\sin x$ need not coincide in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Q}_{p}$.

This false proof appears in Neal Koblitz's *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Fnctions*.

Answer (score 12):

Let $\displaystyle \int$ denote $\displaystyle \int_0^x (\cdot ) dx$. Consider solving the equation
$$\int f = f-1.$$
Rearranging, we get that
$$f - \int f = 1 \implies \left(1 -\int \right)f = 1$$
Hence, $$f = \dfrac1{1 - \displaystyle\int} = \left(1 + \int + \int \int + \int \int \int + \cdots \right)1\\ = 1 + \int_0^x 1 dx + \int_0^x \int_0^x 1 dx  + \int_0^x \int_0^x \int_0^x 1 dx + \cdots = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots = e^x$$which indeed satisfies the equation.

Adapted from this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/jokes-in-the-sense-of-littlewood-examples/38910#38910). [The post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38856/) has lot of other interesting answers as well.

Comment: Is that proof really that false?

As an example, on $(\mathcal C([0,1/2]),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ the operator $\int$ you defined has norm $\|\int\|_{\mathcal L (\mathcal C([0,1/2]))}=1/2$ and all the operations you carry seem to be legitimate. Although it would be better to use two different letters for the identity on $\mathcal C([0,1/2])$ and the constant function equal to one.

Answer (score 4):

What I have in my mind is [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), which says that if $p$ is a prime number, then 
$$(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod p.$$

The fake proof I have learned is the following: 
Since $p=p-1+1$, by taking factorial on both sides, we have
$$p!=(p-1+1)!=(p-1)!+1!=(p-1)!+1.$$
Now taking mod $p$, we obtain
$$0\equiv(p-1)!+1 \pmod p.$$

Of course the "proof" is wrong. The gap occurs because factorial is not distributing in the sense that $(a+b)!\neq a!+b!$ in general. In fact, same "proof" would work without assuming $p$ is prime.

Comment: I think its obvious to see the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple "proof" of four color theorem:

https://superliminal.com/4color/

unfortunately I still can't see the gap in it.

Comment: In figure 2b, the green-red and green-blue paths can cross through each other. Therefore, after we swap yellow/blue inside the green-red path, it may be that we thereby break the green-blue path. And since there are now _two_ blue neighbors of $V$, the argument that a green-blue path must exist cannot be repeated.

Comment: This link is now broken. Could anyone provide an updated URL?

Comment: @BSplitter:  An updated URL is [here](https://superliminal.com/4color/).   I'm not going to edit the (community wiki) Answer above because the content is not really "simple" in my view (but your view might differ).