# Best Fake Proofs? (A M.SE April Fools Day collection)

Tags: soft-question, big-list, fake-proofs

In honor of April Fools Day $2013$, I'd like this question to collect the best, most convincing fake proofs of impossibilities you have seen.

I've posted one as an answer below. I'm also thinking of a geometric one where the "trick" is that it's very easy to draw the diagram wrong and have two lines intersect in the wrong place (or intersect when they shouldn't). If someone could find and link this, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Are we looking to avoid oldies and elementary *proofs*?

Comment: A grad student I know has a wonderful proof involving Fermat's Last Theorem that $\sqrt2^n$ is irrational for all $n$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265853/too-simple-to-be-true/294921#294921

Comment: @user47805, can you post it, here?

Comment: One of the best *ever* fake, or at least apparently-fake, proofs in mathematics goes more or less as 

"I've found a truly wonderful proof but the margin is too $\rlap{-----------}{\text{...ejem,ejem...marginal...er...}}$  small to contain it..."

Comment: Some inspiration for fake proofs: http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~berwin/humour/invalid.proofs.html

Comment: There is this book http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Fallacies-Flaws-Flimflam-Spectrum/dp/0883855291/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1364876834&sr=8-2&keywords=mathematical+fallacies with one of the best collection I have seen.

Comment: See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069507/is-every-parallelogram-a-rectangle

Answer (score 199):

$$x^2=\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{(x\text{ times})}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}[\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{(x\text{ times})}]$$
$$2x=1+1+\cdots+1=x$$
$$2=1$$

Comment: Nice one. You took one $x$ as a variable and the other $x$ as constant!.

Comment: Also, the first statement isn't true unless $x$ is a positive integer, so it can hardly be used with differentiation by $x$ regardless. After all, $\sin \pi x=0$ is true for all integers $x$, but that doesn't mean we can differentiate both sides to get equality. @boywholived

Comment: @Thomas Andrews.What you said is right and is a better reason too.

Comment: @boywholived No, your argument is good too - he is essentially differentiating $xy$ by $x$ and then substituting $y=x$.

Comment: $x+x+...+x(\left \lceil x \right \rceil\text{ times})+x\cdot(x-\left \lceil x \right \rceil)$. May be this could be another *fake* example . Proof that $\left \lceil x\right\rceil$ is differentiable!.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I hope you are trolling ...

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera "$+$" not "$\times$".

Comment: http://www.dougshaw.com/findtheerror/FTEdiff.html

Comment: @spin the L'Hopital's one may be worth posting.

Comment: You would think I was kidding, but I was not. Thank god for the 'delete' button. Go ahead guys, go delete your comment. Go. Now. C'mon, you can do it...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I don't get it - If $\sin \pi x$ is equal to zero, then why isn't its derivative, i.e. $\pi \cos \pi x$ equal to zero too?

Comment: Should the last line be $x =0$?

Comment: rhs is only valid when x is positive integer , and if so then would not be continuous and differentiable

Answer (score 155):

[image]

Endless chocolate bar (I do not know the author of this animation)

Comment: Also see [Missing square puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle) and [Dissection Fallacy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DissectionFallacy.html) (making it into a chocolate bar is pretty recent innovation intended to make the paradox accessible to non-math-enthusiasts that's been going around the memesphere lately).

Comment: For those wondering... the two large pieces get taller as they move--watch their bottoms closely.

Comment: In light of ErikE's comment, not really math. Still nice eye candy though. Pun intended.

Comment: @Yoni, it is math.  See the Expert's link for the missing square puzzle. It's connected to solving $ax+by = 1$ in integers.

Comment: @KCd If it was related to the missing square puzzle (as I originally thought), then sure.  But it's not.  The size of that piece is actually changing through the animation.

Comment: Here is an animation explaining the trick: http://i.imgur.com/nA53dlx.gif

Comment: Wait, isn't this just the two-dimensional version of Banach-Tarski?

Answer (score 126):

Proof that a dog has $9$ legs:

No dog has $5$ legs,

A dog has $4$ more legs than no dog.

A dog has $9$ legs

*Source: Foolproof: A Sampling of Mathematical Folk Humour, P Renteln, A Dundes*

Comment: Cries logical Bobby to Ned, will you dare // 
A bet, which has most legs, a mare, or no mare. // 
A mare, to be sure, replied Ned, with a grin, // 
And fifty I’ll lay, for I’m certain to win. // 
Quoth Bob, you have lost, sure as you are alive, // 
A mare has but four legs, and no mare has five.

Comment: By that theorem, a ham sandwich is better than eternal happiness.

Comment: Actually, given that animals are occasionally born with two heads, I think the assumption that no dog has 5 legs is probably invalid. It's probably safer to use a larger number like 100.

Comment: ^ But what if genetic science finds a way to create a centipedal dog?

Comment: I'll just leave this here... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FavUpD_IjVY

Answer (score 104):

Simple one:

$1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)} = \sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1} = i\cdot i = -1$

Comment: $\sqrt{a\cdot b}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$. Is valid only when both $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Comment: @boywholived: yes, the idea is that these are fake proofs.

Comment: A nice variant of this that does not require complex numbers is $-1=(-1)^{1/3}=(-1)^{2/6}=((-1)^2)^{1/6}=1^{1/6}=1$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes...but boywholived is pointing out the problem with the proof...valuable to those who may not see the issue.  After all, if the problem with the proof was obvious, it wouldn't qualify as much of a joke.

Comment: @boywholived It is valid only when at least one of them is non-negative.

Comment: It seems that Euler himself was confused with this. See [here]( https://webspace.utexas.edu/aam829/1/m/Euler_files/EulerMonthly.pdf)

Comment: @boywholived You are wrong, it's not valid __only__ when they are both positive. In general $(xy)^z=x^zy^z$ for any __complex__ $y,z$ and real $x\ge0$.

Comment: @BabyDragon although a nice fake proof but: $$b^{\frac{n}{m}}=(b^n)^{\frac{1}{m}}=(b^{\frac{1}{m}})^n$$ requires a sufficient condition that , $b$ is not negative when $n$ is even.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem That is exactly what makes it nice, at least in the context of teaching. I have seen way to many textbooks and instructors, either gloss over theses conditions or not even mention them. It is something of a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @BabyDragon I agree.

Comment: @BabyDragon The cube roots are not needed to show the fallacy. The fallacy can also be presented like this: $-1=(-1)^{2/2}=((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$.

Answer (score 97):

Let us prove the following (obviously) wrong proposition:

$\underline{\text{Proposition}}$
All positive natural numbers are definable in under eleven words.

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$
Suppose for the sake of contradiction(!) that not all positive natural numbers are definable in under eleven words. Then there is a smallest integer $n\in\mathbb N$ which is not definable in under eleven words. But this number is 
$$
\color{brown}
{
\text
{ 
the smallest positive integer not definable in under eleven words, 
}
}
$$
therefore, it is definable in ten words. Contradiction!

--

For more information see the wikipedia article [Berry paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox).

Comment: So which number is "the largest positive integer definable in ten words or less"?

Comment: @JoeZeng "Ackermann with (Ackermann with (Graham, Graham), Ackermann with (Graham, Graham))"? Does that count?

Comment: @JoeZeng why should there need to be one?

Comment: @Max all nonempty sets of positive natural numbers have a smallest element...

Comment: @crf: Can you prove there isn't one?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I was looking for a proof myself. If you want to play like that, I can do "Tree of tree of tree of tree of Graham's number", where "tree" refers to the [TREE function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_tree_theorem).

Comment: Although to be honest, "Tree of tree of tree of tree of eighty-six" would have more than sufficed.

Comment: I love that one :)
The thing is, in the ZF axioms we have "the seperation schema", which says that if X is a set and phi is a formula, then there is a set Y such that for all a, (a /in Y) iff (a /in X and phi(a)).
This is what you use here to get "the set of numbers not definable in 10 words or less". The thing is, the seperation schema demands that phi will be definable in first-order logic, which it isn't here :P

Comment: Interestingly, one way to prove that the halting problem is unsolvable is to try to make this rigorous. If you can solve the halting problem, you can write a program that takes an input N, and then finds all outputs of programs of length $M$ with input $K$, with $M,K\leq N$, then find the least natural number not output in any of these cases. Then feed the length of this program to itself. With a solution to the halting problem, you can write this program easily.

Answer (score 84):

A friend of mine came up with this proof that all perfect numbers are even. A little more advanced than your usual fake proof that $0=1$.

Assume $$2n = \sum_{d|n} d$$

Then by Möbius inversion:

$$n =\sum_{d|n} 2d\cdot\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$

and therefore $n$ is even.

Comment: This is a great example! I heard it over 20 years ago, so I doubt your friend is the first person to make this "observation".

Comment: @KCd Hah, it was at math camp in the early 80s, so we're talking 20 years ago for me, too.

Comment: It was at math camp for me too, in the late 80s. Did your camp happen to be located in Ohio?

Comment: Yep, the Ross program. :) Guess it was the same instance.

Comment: @Thomas: You kids! :-) I did it in $1963$, when it was still at Notre Dame.

Comment: This is pretty cool ... though it would be better if the first perfect number $n=6$ didn't reveal it to be false.

Comment: @KCd I think Brian was saying he went to the program back then, when it was at Notre Dame, not that this particular proof was from that era. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Brian, is Tom right about my misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @KCd: Yes, Thomas’s interpretation is correct: I was talking about the program, not the proof. By the way, Wikipedia says that the program started in $1957$, so its longevity is pretty impressive.

Comment: I know it's not appropriate to "explain" a joke, but is this a valid proof of: "IF _all_ numbers are perfect, THEN all numbers are even."

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Actually a stronger statement: if all divisors of perfect number $n$ are perfect, then $n$ is even. Too bad that $1$ isn't perfect.

Answer (score 73):

$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = x\cdot\frac{1}{x} - \int x\,d\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = 1 + \int x\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = 1 + \int \frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$0 = 1 $$

Comment: From C to shining C!

Answer (score 70):

"Proof" that $1$ is the largest natural number.

Let $n$ be the largest natural number. Then, $n^2$, being a natural number, is less than or equal to $n$.
Therefore $n^2-n=n(n-1)\leq 0$. Hence, $0\leq n\leq 1$. Therefore $n=1$.

Comment: I know these are all joke proofs, but this is also a good reminder about the importance of proving the *existence* of a mathematical object before you go on to prove things about said object. Otherwise you can prove lots of interesting but nonsensical things.

Comment: @JoshChen Sometimes it's good to prove some properties of a mathematical object first - if some of them give you an easy proof of nonexistence.

Comment: @JoshChen that's the one I was searching for. Nice objection!

Comment: It _does_ prove that the largest natural number, if it exists, is equal to 1.

Comment: Do you have any reference about this? I am sure I read it in Wikipedia somewhere but I can't remember it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot seem to find the exact reference, but if I'm not mistaken, I learned of this fake proof from a book by Luc Tartar. His purpose was to illustrate (in the context of the calculus of variations) the danger in assuming the existence of an extremum without proving it.

Answer (score 64):

> **Proof that Riemann hypothesis is true:**

*(1) At least one of the following statements is true*

*(2) The above statement is false*

*(3) Riemann hypothesis is true*

Comment: Interesting, I have a feeling the fallacy may have something to do with Godel's incompleteness theorems, am I close?

Comment: Well I do not know the above theorem, but I know the fallacy is regarding that "Every mathematical statement is not necessarily either true or false".

Comment: For example consider: **"This statement is false"**, the cyclicity generated by its truth and falsehood makes the statement to be classifiable as none.

Comment: While I enjoy this sort of self-reference, the real problem with this proof is that it includes unjustified (and potentially false) premises, in the same way that "(1) The following statement is true; (2) The Riemann hypothesis is true" does.

Comment: @GregMartin: There is a difference: in your example, both (1) and (2) could be taken to be false, or both to be true, and there is no inconsistency in either case. In the above (fake) proof in the answer though, (1) is not a premise, but can be "proved" to be true: if (1) is false, then both (2) and (3) are false and in particular (2) is false, which means that (1) is true, which is a contradiction. Therefore (1) is true, and therefore (2) is false, and therefore as at least one of (2) and (3) are true, (3) must be true.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: yes, that is am important difference - but not a difference relevant to my point. I'm pointing out that the flaw in the proof is traceable simply to the first instant, when we accepted the trio-of-statements as being "true" - when in fact there's no reason to think that it is. That is the same as with my more pedestrian example ... and also the same as "Either this sentence is false or the Riemann hypothesis is true".

Comment: @GregMartin: I don't understand what you mean by accepting the trio of statements as true: we did no such thing (and in fact "proved" statement (2) to be false). Self-reference is crucial to the argument (the way (1) refers to (2) which refers back to (1)), which is why your first example shows nothing, while your second example with "either this sentence is false..." does. If you mean accepting that each statement in the system is either true or false, yes that is the flaw as Grobber already pointed out above before you first commented — and self-reference is required for it to give anything.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: it’s not unrelated to Gödel’s incompleteness; but it’s most closely related, I think, to [Tarski’s undefinability of truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem), which essentially states that no reasonably strong logical system can talk about truth-values of its own statements.  The two main ingredients of that are (a) some deep thought to formalize precisely what that self-reference  means, and (b) having done this, a quick derivation of a contradiction.  Part (b) can be done — among other ways — by the present false proof, with RH replaced by absurdity.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: To add a bit to your above comment, not only is it because truth is undefinable in a **classical** theory that interprets arithmetic, it is crucially because of LEM. If one accepts LEM only for statements that can be justified to have a boolean truth value, all such paradoxes (see also Quine's paradox) vanish. Furthermore, it is possible to have self-reflection in a non-classical theory, such as Tarski's theory of truth, but necessarily (by incompleteness) any such theory cannot interpret arithmetic without being uncomputable.

Answer (score 54):

The scientist/engineer's proof that all odd numbers are prime...

- 1 is prime
- 3 is prime
- 5 is prime
- 7 is prime
- 9 - experimental error
- 11 is prime
- 13 is prime
- 15 - experimental error
- 17 is prime
- 19 is prime

Therefore, by extension (ignoring the scientific errors), all odd numbers are prime.

Comment: Someone with an art degree would say: all odd numbers are prime? Let's check: 1 is prime, 2 is prime, 3 is prime, 4 is prime, 5 is prime, ...

Comment: Isn't "$1$ is prime" some kind of error too?

Comment: @WChargin: Experimenter error.

Comment: 3 isn't prime! It's third! :)

Comment: You're bound to get about 1/20 false positives. The logical extension of this is that the number of odd numbers is countable - 20 times the number of odds that erroneously came out as composite.

Comment: This is so funny!

Answer (score 46):

All cats have the same color by induction on the number of cats.

Base case: If there is only one cat, then it doesn't matter the color. They all have the same color.

Inductive step: Fix $n$. Suppose for any set of $n$ cats they have the same color. Consider any set of $n+1$ cats. Then cats 1 through n have the same color by inductive hypothesis. There is only one remaining to check, but we also know that cats $2$ through $n+1$ have the same color by the inductive hypothesis. Thus they must all have the same color (for example, because they all have the same color as the second one in this proof). QED.

...But clearly not all cats have the same color...

Comment: There are a few typos: you typed group instead of set and cats instead of horses.

Comment: In the internet age, I think it is more appropriate to prove that "all cats on youtube have the same color"  instead of "all horses have the same color."

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure how group/set actually matters here. Also, I intentionally didn't use "horses" so that people couldn't just google to figure out the error.

Comment: What if $n = 2$?

Comment: I suspect that the inductive step makes an implicit assumption $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Since the above commenters seem to be unsure:  The problem is that the proof assumes the two sets *(1 thru n, and 2 thru n+1)* intersect, which they do not for n = 1.

Comment: The inductive step is valid for $n+1\ge 3$. So this leads to the "theorem" that if any ***two*** cats have the same color, then any finite set of cats consists of one color only.

Comment: 1 is not a valid base case because you are talking about "1 through n" and "2 through n+1$.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Why do we need them to intersect ?

Answer (score 43):

Theorem:  If we mark $n$ points on a circle and connect each point to every other point by a straight line, the number of regions that the interior of the circle is divided into is $2^{n-1}$.

Proof:  First let's collect numerical evidence.

When $n = 1$ there is one region (the whole disc).

When $n = 2$ there are two regions (two half-discs).

When $n = 3$ there are 4 regions (three lune-like regions and one triangle in the middle).

When $n = 4$ there are 8 regions, and if you're still not convinced then try $n=5$ and you'll find 16 regions if you count carefully.

Our proof in general will be by induction on $n$.  Assuming the theorem is true for $n$ points, consider a circle with $n+1$ points on it.  Connecting $n$ of them together in pairs produces $2^{n-1}$ regions in the disc, and then connecting the remaining point to all the others will divide the previous regions into two parts, thereby giving us $2 \cdot 2^{n-1} = 2^n$ regions.

Or does it...

Comment: Is this true generically?

Comment: A good lesson in the dangers of both making assumptions based on examples, and of lacking rigor in your proofs.

Comment: The sad part about this particular one for me is that I actually presented this proof in foundations once (set theory, logic).  *sigh*

Comment: "try n=5 and you'll find 16 regions if you count carefully" - it's 11 really, isn't it?

Comment: @Roster: it is 16, not 11.  Remember to connect *each* of the 5 points to every other point by a straight line.

Comment: @Baby Dragon: Try 6 and see what happens.

Comment: It depends on the way you place the dots, but the maximum number of regions is given by the sequence $$\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 57, 99, 163, 256, 386, 562, 794, 1093, 1471, 1941, 2517, 3214, 4048, 5036, 6196,\\ 7547, 9109, 10903, 12951, 15276, 17902, 20854, 24158, 27841, 31931, 36457, 41449, 46938,\\ 52956, 59536, 66712, 74519, 82993, 92171,\ldots\}$$. i.e. [A006522](http://oeis.org/A006522)$+n$

Comment: Actually it is in OEIS directly: [A000127](http://oeis.org/A000127)

Comment: It is interesting that there is actually a polynomial expression for this: $$a(n)=\frac{1}{24}n^4-\frac{1}{4}n^3+\frac{23}{24}n^2-\frac{3}{4}n+1$$

Comment: @Spenser: Yes, the small powers of 2 happen to match the polynomial sequence $1 + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4}$.  Similarly, $1 + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} + \cdots + \binom{n}{2r}$ equals $2^{n-1}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 2r+1$, and it equals $2^{n-1} - 1$ for $n = 2(r+1)$.

Comment: 3Blue1Browm tackled this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84hEmGHw3J8&list=PLZHQObOWTQDOqzmnORfqizZK-TcBE09jR

Answer (score 36):

**Zero$^{th}$ fundamental theorem of calculus**: $$\int\limits_{0}^{a}{f(x) dx}=0\space \space  \quad \quad \forall a \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \forall f(x) \in\mathcal{R}\left(\left(0,a\right)\right)$$

---

**Proof**

It's well known that $$\int\limits_{0}^{0}{f(x) dx}=0\space \space  \quad \quad \forall f(x) \space \tag{1} $$

**Case I**

When $a=0$ 
The theorem at this case follows directly from $(1) $

**Case II**

When $a\neq 0$

Let $\large I=\int\limits_{0}^{a}{f(x) dx}$
Let $\large \sin{\frac{\pi \cdot x}{a}}=t $. Then $\large \frac{\pi}{a}\cos{\frac{\pi \cdot x}{a}}dx={dt}$
$$\cos{\frac{\pi \cdot x}{a}}=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{\frac{\pi \cdot x}{a}}}=\sqrt{1-t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{a}{\pi}\cdot\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

As we have introduced a substitution we should change the variables of the limit.
$$\begin{cases}
x=0 & \text{then } t=0, 
\text{ (lower limit)} \\
x=a & \text{then } t=0, \text{ (upper limit)}\end{cases}$$

We have $$I=\int\limits_{0}^{a}{f(x) dx}=\large  \int\limits_{0}^{0}{\left(\frac{f(\frac{a}{\pi}\cdot\arcsin{t})}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt\right)}=0$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: You could change $\pi$ to $a$ , $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and you would get a generalization.

Comment: There’s no reason to consider Case I separately — the current Case II covers it anyway (nowhere in Case II do you use the assumption that $a ≠ 0$).

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine. I think we should consider case 1 $a=0$. Otherwise our initial substitution $\sin{\frac{\pi \cdot x}{\boxed{a}}}=t$ would . . . ..

Comment: I don't get what is wrong with this. Help!

Comment: @AGoogler: The first thing wrong I notice is that when $\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\theta\leq \pi$, $\cos(\theta)\neq \sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$.

Comment: @AGoogler The inverse of sine is not well-defined in this domain.

Comment: (Sorry for the necropost) But is it also true more generally that because $sin(\frac{\pi x}{a})$ is not a diffeomorphism between domains (it's not invertible), you can't define a proper pullback to integrate the form?

Answer (score 35):

All numbers are interesting.

Assume there is at least one uninteresting number. Then there is a non-empty set of uninteresting numbers. There is also a smallest uninteresting number. That makes it an interesting number so we remove it from the set of uninteresting numbers and repeat until we have removed all uninteresting numbers from that set.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the set of uninteresting numbers is non-empty.

Comment: I guess so. Of course if we did start with an empty set of uninteresting numbers there would be no need for the proof.

Comment: I mean instead of "then there is a set of uninteresting numbers", so you can then conclude, by the [well ordering principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) that "there is also a smallest uninteresting number".

Comment: I have heard this proof with "There is a smallest uninteresting number. Hey, that's pretty interesting! Contradiction."

Comment: Works for the natural numbers at least. I guess it would work for the reals by applying Zorn's lemma...

Comment: [In this blog post](http://blog.plover.com/math/uninteresting-numbers.html) I argue that there exists a minimally interesting real number.

Comment: @MJD, interestingly (no pun intended), your blog post needs the notion of *interesting property* in order to define *interesting number*. But there are only countably many (describable) properties hene they are readily well-ordered and thus either all or no property is interesting ...

Comment: Only if you can prove that there is a canonically interesting well-ordering. Unlike the integers, there is no single pre-eminent ordering of an arbitrary countable set.

Comment: Is 1729 interesting?

Answer (score 26):

Here is a another proof that "$0=1"$. $$0=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots=1-1+1-1+1\cdots=1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)\cdots=1+0+0+\cdots=1$$ Of course, this proof fails because the series $\Sigma (-1)^n$ is divergent.

Comment: How about this one: Let S = 1+2+4+8+16+... Then 2S = 2+4+8+16+32+... Subtraction of first minus second gives -S = 1 ans so S = -1 therefore -1 = 1+2+4+8+16+.....

Comment: @imranfat: That is actually true when working in the $2$-adics...

Comment: Am I not getting it or we just missed -1 after third equals sign just before the fourth one?

Comment: @TMM: I think proofs like these are canonical examples of proofs which are false in one setting (e.g. standard convergence over the reals), but which in other settings with the same formalism (e.g. p-adics, or formal power series, or even just other notions of convergence/summability over the reals) may turn  out to be true, and quite useful.

Comment: @Peter The original proof actually has applications in topology as the [Mazur swindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg–Mazur_swindle) where infinite sums are defined (but addition is not necessarily cancellative).

Answer (score 23):

The proof that $\pi = 4$, discussed here: [Is value of $\pi = 4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4)

1. Inscribe a unit circle inside a square with side $4$.
2. Repeat the following: For every vertex of the polygon (at first the square) that does not touch the circle, "fold it" so it touches the circle (by creating two additional vertices, so that all angles are right angles).
3. The length of the polygon is always $4$, but the polygon converges to the circle, so $\pi = 4$.

Comment: Fractals can be tricky when it comes to perimeter.

Comment: What does converge, however, is the area.

Comment: Very true; math is full of such convergent/divergent conundrums. The Gabriel's Horn, for instance, has infinite surface area (because it has infinite length/depth and at every point along its length a nonzero diameter), but a finite convergent volume.

Comment: @KeithS:  Careful, if one uses $\frac{1}{x^2}$ to make Gabriel's horn instead of $\frac{1}{x}$, then both the volume and surface area area finite, despite the fact that it "has infinite length/depth and at every point along its length a nonzero diamter."

Comment: So, $\lim_{}{4} =\pi$?

Answer (score 20):

Timothy Chow has posted a proof that $1=0$ via an illicit differentiation under the integral sign [on his website](http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/mathstuff/proof.pdf), here is a quote:

> **Proof that $1=0$**
>
> Given any $x$, we have (by using the substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{y}$)
>   $$
> \int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}}dy=\left[xe^-{\frac{x^2}{y}}\right]^1_0=xe^{-x^2}.
> $$
>   Therefore, for all $x$,
>   $$
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2) &=& \frac{d}{dx} (xe^{-x^2}) \\
>                  &=& \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{y^2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}} dy \\
>                  &=& \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{x^3}{y^2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}}\right) dy \\
>                  &=& \int_0^1 e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}} \left(\frac{3x^2}{y^2} - \frac{2x^4}{y^3}\right) dy.
> \end{array}
> $$
>   Now set $x=0$; the left-hand side is $e^0(1-0)=1$, but the right-hand side is $\int_0^1 0\ dy=0$.

Comment: "Illicit differentiation" sounds **so** much more exciting than implicit differentiation.

Comment: There is no need for any kind of differentiation under the integral sign. The essence of the argument is this: for $a > 0$, $\int_1^\infty ae^{-ax}dx = e^{-a}$. Now let $a \rightarrow 0^{+}$. The left side has limit $\int_1^\infty 0dx = 0$ and the right side has limit $e^{-0} = 1$. Maybe not...

Answer (score 20):

Here's a "proof" of $e^{x} = 1$ for all $x$.
$$\exp(x) = \exp(i2\pi\cdot\frac{x}{i2\pi}) = \exp(i2\pi)^{\frac{x}{i2\pi}} = 1 ^{\frac{x}{i2\pi}} = 1.$$

Comment: This is a nice one, would you mind stating which = sign is incorrect? I assume the second one because of incorrect rules of exponents since there are complex numbers involved?

Comment: Yes, it's the second equality :)

Answer (score 18):

Here's a fake proof that there are no natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$. Suppose it were the case and further suppose, without loss of generality, that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Then $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$ and so $$2q^{2} = p^{2}, \tag{*}$$ which means that $p$ is even. Thus $p=2r$ for some natural number $r$. Plugging that into (*) gives $2q^{2} = 4r^{2}$, so that $q^{2} = 2r^{2}$, which means $q$ is also even, contrary to the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

Comment: That proof is not fake. That is a proof by contradiction, a well established method for disproving conjectures

Comment: @imranfat (I think that's his joke, considering it's April Fools day...)

Answer (score 16):

Let $f(x) = 1$. It's easy to see that its Fourier transform is $0$ almost everywhere, so $\hat {\hat f}(x) = 0$. By the inversion theorem, $1 = 0$.

Answer (score 16):

Let me prove that the number $1$ is a multiple of $3$.

To accomplish such a wonderful result we are going to use the symbol $\equiv$ to denote "congruent modulo $3$". Thus, what we need to prove is that $1 \equiv 0$. Next I give you the proof:

$1\equiv 4$ 
$\quad \Rightarrow \quad$ 
$2^1\equiv 2^4$ 
$\quad \Rightarrow \quad$ 
$2\equiv 16$ 
$\quad \Rightarrow \quad$ 
$2\equiv 1$ 
$\quad \Rightarrow \quad$ 
$2-1\equiv 1-1$
$\quad \Rightarrow \quad$ 
$1\equiv 0$.

Comment: How "does" $2 \equiv 16 \implies 2 \equiv 1$? Is it because $1 \equiv 4$ and $16 / 4 \in \mathbb{N}$? That doesn't seem to follow... what am I missing?

Comment: @WChargin:  That part's just legitimate transitivity, with $16 = 1 \text{  (mod 3)}$.  I still can't think of anyone whom the exponentiation right at the start would fool, though.

Comment: @boumol WHat is the mistake in this argument?

Comment: @Babai, $a \equiv b \Rightarrow a^k \equiv b^k$, but does not imply $k^a \equiv k^b$

Comment: @boumol $2^1 \equiv 2$ mod 3 but $2^4 \equiv 1$ mod 3. Multiplying two natural numbers that are the same mod 3 always gets you a number the same mod 3 but that's not the case for natural number exponentation.

Answer (score 15):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1k&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac1{2k+1}+\frac1{2k+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{4k+3}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac{2(2k+1)}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}+\frac1{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1k+\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{(2k+1)(2k+2)}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1k+\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1k+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1k+\ln 2\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $\ln 2=0$, and $2=e^{\ln 2}=e^0=1$.

---

The legitimate version of this shows that $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k=H_{2n}-H_n\;,$$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number, and with the observation that

$$\ln\left(2-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}x<H_{2n}-H_n<\frac1{n+1}+\int_n^{2n}\frac{dx}x=\frac1{n+1}+\ln 2$$

is one way to show that $\sum\limits_{k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k=\ln 2$.

Comment: This is also another proof that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Or does it just prove the harmonic series doesn't converge absolutely?

Comment: @Jason: Same thing, since it’s a positive series.

Comment: @Brian:  Oh, Duh!  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

$$(n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1$$

Expansion:   $$(n+1)^2-(2n+1) = n^2$$

Subtract from both sides:   $$(n+1)^2-(2n+1)-n(2n+1) = n^2-n(2n+1)$$

Add to both sides:   $$(n+1)^2-(n+1)(2n+1) = n^2-n(2n+1)$$

Factor:   $$(n+1)^2-(n+1)(2n+1)+\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4} = n^2-n(2n+1)+\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4}$$

Add to both sides:   $$\left[(n+1)-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right]^2 = \left[n-\frac{2n+1}{2}\right]^2$$

Square root:   $$(n+1)-\frac{2n+1}{2} = n-\frac{2n+1}{2}$$

Subtract from both sides:   $$n+1 = n$$

Subtract from both sides:   $$1 = 0$$

Impossible!

Comment: Took me a while to figure this one out. I typed each expression in my TI and left hand side equals right hand side. Until I reache the square root part. The problem is the square root. If A² = B² that does not automatically imply A=B, it could also be A=-B  That's an awesome example!

Answer (score 9):

[Here's](http://www.dougshaw.com/findtheerror/) a fun compilation of fake proofs in calculus. One of them is already here, but I'll give another example:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{1 + x^4} &=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\frac{1}{x^4}}{\frac{1}{x^4} + 1}dx\\
u &= \frac{1}{x^4}\\
du &= -\frac{4}{x^5}dx\\
\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{1 + x^4} &=\int_1^1\frac{u}{u+1}\left(-\frac{u^{-5/4}}{4}\right)\,du\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\int_1^1\frac{du}{\sqrt[4]{u}\left(u + 1\right)}\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
However, one look at the graph of $\frac{1}{1 + x^4}$ (or a quick estimate) tells us that the integral in question is certainly nonzero!

Comment: Please look at the moderator's note at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @boywholived Right, I had posted that there because this post had linked there. I have since deleted the answer from the "duplicate" question.

Comment: The answer to integral is not incorrect at all! It is just that you wanted to calculate the area under the curve and that didn't work. The answer to an integral itself does not always have to give you the area under the curve unless that is what the question states.

Comment: @imranfat It's we can also see that the integral is nonzero because $\frac{1}{1 + x^4} > 0$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I agree, so if the question is "Calculate the area under the curve" then you are correct. What I am saying is that the answer to an arbitrary integral does not have to be an area under the curve perse

Comment: @imranfat I agree that in general an integral does not have to represent the area under a curve. However, in this case, we can interpret the integral in question as the area under the curve of the graph of $1/(1 + x^4)$ without fear, and that's one way of seeing that this calculation cannot be correct.

Comment: If the calculations are correct and this integral can be interpret as the area under the curve, and the area is not zero, what´s wrong here?

Comment: @Integral the substitution we consider is invalid: here's the theorem:
Suppose that $f$ is continuous on an open interval $I$. *Let $u$ and $u'$ be continuous on an open interval $J$*, and assume that the range of $u$ is contained in $I$. If $a,b\in J$, then $\int_a^b f(u(x))u'(x)\,dx = \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} f(u)\,du$. Certainly, the $u$ we use here is not continuous on the interval in question, $(-1 - \epsilon,1 + \epsilon)$.

Comment: It's worth remembering that results in calculus can ***always*** be checked by writing a program to calculate successive approximations of the curve/area/arc length etc.

Comment: @Stahl can I also say that dividing inside the integral by $x^4$ at the beggining is only valid for $x \neq 0$, but $0$ is inside the integration domain then it is not a valid step?

Answer (score 6):

We shall prove that $x=e^{\pi/2} \approx 4.8$ is a solution to $x^x=x$.

First, we compute $i^i = e^{i \log i} = e^{i(\pi/2i)} = e^{- \pi/2}$. Next we compute $i^{i^i} = e^{-pi/2 i} = -i$. Then $x=i^{i^{i^i}}=(-i)^i=e^{i\log (-i)}=e^{i(-\pi/2 i)}=e^{\pi/2}$.

Finally, $x^i=i^{i^{i^{i^i}}}=e^{i \pi/2}=i$.

Raise each side of the previous equation to the $i^{i^i}$th power. We get
$$ x^{i^{i^{i^i}}}={i^{i^{i^i}}}$$
or
$$x^x=x$$
where $x=e^{\pi/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$1=2$: **A Proof using Complex Numbers**

This supposed proof uses complex numbers. If you're not familiar with them, there's a brief introduction to them given below.
The Fallacious Proof:

> Step 1: $-1/1 = 1/-1$
> Step 2: Taking the square root of both sides: $\sqrt{-1/1} = \sqrt{1/-1}$.
> Step 3: Simplifying: $\sqrt{-1} / \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{1} / \sqrt{-1}$
> Step 4: In other words, $i/1 = 1/i$.
> Step 5: Therefore, $i / 2 = 1 / (2i)$,
> Step 6: $i/2 + 3/(2i) = 1/(2i) + 3/(2i)$,
> Step 7: $i (i/2 + 3/(2i) ) = i ( 1/(2i) + 3/(2i) )$,
> Step 8: $(i^2)/2 + (3i)/2i = i/(2i) + (3i)/(2i)$,
> Step 9: $(-1)/2 + 3/2 = 1/2 + 3/2$,
> Step 10: and this shows that $1=2$.

See if you can figure out in which step the fallacy lies.

Comment: Hint : Its Steps 2 and 3

Comment: I would say the mistake is in Step $4$, where it is assumed that $i$ is the square root of $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

> Whatever goes up, must come down

Rules of Mathematics prove that this is a wrong rule and should be discarded

**Proof:**

```
Eq 1. Goes Up = Comes Down

Eq 2. (1 / Goes Up) = (1 / Comes Down)

Since Goes Up means inverse of Comes Down, hence

That means Goes Up = (1 / Comes Down)

From Eq2, we can say

Comes Down = (1 / Comes Down)

Which is Impossible!
```

Hence proved that this is wrong, and **Whatever goes up must keep going up!**

Comment: Well, what if `Comes Down = 1`?

Comment: How would that be so?

Comment: I dunno, you could arbitrarily set it to be that, I suppose.

Comment: I would say mathematically, Goes up would be the additive inverse, and not multiplicative, of comes down.