# What do I do wrong with Möbius method of inversion?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I use the Möbius inversion with polynomials as e.g. in the well-known inversion formula
of the cyclotomic polynomials.
So I have $$p_{2n}(x)=\prod_{d|n}(2q_d(x))^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$ 
Now I get the correct ( CAS tested ) formula
$$2q_n(x)=\prod_{d|n}p_{2d}(x)$$
But : if I separate the factor 2 into $$\prod_{d|n}2^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$
I calculate $$2^{\sum_{d|n}\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$
and this is $1$ for $n>1$ and so dissappears. So would result the wrong formula
$$q_n(x)=\prod_{d|n}p_{2d}(x)$$
Where is the error in my reasoning ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Mobius inversion here because you need  $$p_{2n}(x)=\prod_{d\mid n} q_d(x)^{\mu(n/d)}$$ for all $n$, but it is not true for $n=1$.

If you defined $r_n(x)=p_{2n}(x)$ if $n>1$ and $r_1(x)=p_{2}(x)/2=q_1(x)$ if $n=1$, then you'd have:

$$r_n(x)=\prod_{d\mid n} q_d(x)^{\mu(n/d)}$$
for all $n$. Then you'd get that:

$$q_d(x)=\prod_{d\mid n} r_n(x) = \frac 1 2 \prod_{d\mid  n} p_{2d}(x)$$

The mistake is thinking that the statement of MI (additive form) is:

$$\left(g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)\right)\iff\left(f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \mu\left(\frac n d\right)f(d)\right)$$

The correct statement is:

$$\left(\forall n:g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)\right)\iff\left(\forall n:f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \mu\left(\frac n d\right)f(d)\right)$$

One of my [favorite fake proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection/348203#348203) makes this error.

Comment: Thanks for that correct derivation of the result. But i am still confused why I cant take the product of the 2 factor out. Please correct the typo on the right side of your last two formulas : g instead of f as factor at the $\mu$-function.

Comment: You can take that product out, but that product is $2$ if $n=1$ and $1$ otherwise. So you don't get the result you think you do...

Comment: You get $p_{2n}(x)=f(n)\cdot \prod q_d(x)^{\mu(n/d)}$, where $f(n) =2$ if $n=1$ and $f(n)=1$ otherwise. So you can apply Mobius inverson to $p_{2n}(x)/f(n)=r_n(x)$, but not to $p_{2n}(x)$.

Comment: Thats clear now. Thank you.