# Fake proofs using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, big-list, fake-proofs

Having gone through the 16-page-list of questions tagged [fake-proofs](/questions/tagged/fake-proofs), and going though both the relevant [MSE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection) and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy), I didn't find a single fake proof that involved *matrices*.

So the question (or challange) here is: **what are some fake proof using matrices?**

In particular, the fake proof should use a property, an operation, ..., specific to matrices (or at least not present in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), e.g.

- Noncommutativity
- (Non-)existence of an inverse
- Matrix sizes
- Operations as $\det$, $\text{trace}$, ...
- Eigenvalues and diagonalization
- Matrix decompositions and normal forms
- ...

**Note:** It does not matter if the result being "proven" is correct or not. The fallacy in the proof itself is what matters.

**Examples:**

1. **Proof that 1 = 0**

> *Proof:* it is a well-known fact that $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. 
>   Now let
>   $$x = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;\;y = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   On the one hand, we have that
>   $$ (x+y)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
>   on the other hand we have
>   $$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Since two matrices are equal if and only if all their entries are equal, we conclude that $1 = 0$.

> The mistake here is that $x$ and $y$  do not commute. Thus $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 \neq x^2 + 2xy + y^2$.

2. **Proof that 2 = 0**

> *Proof:* We know that $\det (AB) = \det (BA)$, since $$\det (AB) = (\det A) (\det B) = (\det B) (\det A) = \det (BA).$$
>   Now consider the matrices
>   $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \; \; B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   We have that
>   $$AB = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;\; BA = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Hence $\det (AB) = 2$ and $\det (BA) = 0$, therefore $2 = 0$.

> The mistake here is that $\det$ is defined for square matrices only, and thus $\det AB = \det BA$ only holds in general if $A$ and $B$ are square.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: First and foremost, from an educational perspective. I like to use "fake proofs" to get a point across to students, e.g. why they can't carelessly switch the order of differentiation, integration, limits, etc. I find that they enjoy the class more if I prove something ridiculous like $1=0$ instead of just warning them about pitfalls, and also that they are more likely to remember to watch out for these pitfalls. And second, because I find it fun to create (and find mistakes in) fake proofs.

Comment: And as to why this question relates to proofs using matrices in particular: I've taught courses on elementary analysis en calculus so far, and I have a good repository of fake proofs there. But there is a good chance I'll be teaching (linear) algebra in the near future...

Answer (score 14):

Here is a fake proof of a true theorem, Cayley-Hamilton.

So the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is $f_A(t) = \textrm{det}(tI-A)$. Then $f_A(A) = \textrm{det}(AI-A) = \textrm{det}(A-A) = \textrm{det}(0) = 0$.

Comment: "this can be made rigorous"

Comment: "Is this clear?"

Comment: @Daminark To reply to your chat message yesterday: yes, this is allowed! I've added this in the questionnaire. (Great proof, by the way!)

Comment: One way to see that it doesn't work is to check what happens with the trace instead of $\det$. But it can be made rigorous by turning the space $R^n$ into an $R[x]$-module via $f$.

Answer (score 7):

To prove:  $0=1$.

Certain identities get funky when we pass over to *infinite-order matrices*.  We see such matrices, for example, in representations of operators in quantum mechanics.

Everyone knows that

$Tr(AB-BA)=Tr(AB)-Tr(BA)=0$.

So let

$A_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j-1}, B_{i,j}=A_{j,i}$

Here $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function, and $i$ and $j$ run through all natural mumbers.

Then $AB-BA$ has a 1 in the upper left position and zeroes everywhere else. The sum of diagonal elments is 1 and yet "$Tr(AB-BA)=0$".

$Tr(AB-BA)=0$ is guaranteed only for finite matrices or, among infinite matrices, when the traces of $AB$ and $BA$ converge absolutely.