# What is going wrong in this "proof" of $0=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

\begin{align}
-20 &= -20\\
16-36 &= 25-45\\
4^2-4\times 9&=5^2-5\times 9\\
4^2-4\times 9+81/4&=5^2-5\times 9+81/4\\
4^2-4\times 9+(9/2)^2&=5^2-5\times 9+(9/2)^2\\
\end{align}

Considering the formula $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$, one has
\begin{align}
(4-9/2)^2&=(5-9/2)^2\\
\sqrt{(4-9/2)^2}&=\sqrt{(5-9/2)^2}\\
4-9/2&=5-9/2\\
4&=5\\
4-4&=5-4\\
0&=1
\end{align}

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ so $\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{b^2}$ does *not* imply $a=b$ but rather $|a|=|b|$. And, indeed, $|4-9/2|=|5-9/2|=1/2$ but $4-9/2 \ne 5-9/2$ and the rest doesn't follow.

Comment: I don't see why this question keeps getting downvotes. I'll give it a +1 just because it is very clearly titled "*spot the mistake*", it is written down in full detail, and correctly tagged as `fake-proofs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Fake Proofs? (A M.SE April Fools Day collection)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here let me simplify your process:

$$
\begin{align}
(-2)^2 = 4 &\implies \sqrt{(-2)^2} = \sqrt{2^2} \\
&\implies -2 = 2 \\
&\implies -2 + 2 = 2 +2  \\
&\implies 0 = 4
\end{align}
$$

QED. Do you see the mistake?

Comment: So, I'm simply give the answer: we cannot root the negative integer,as in question &radic;(4-9/2)<sup>2</sup>=&radic;(5-9/2)<sup>2</sup> explaination: LHS:4-9/2=(8-9)/2 so &radic;((8-9)/2)<sup>2</sup> &radic;(-1/2)<sup>2</sup> &radic;(1/4) (1/2) RHS:5-9/2=(10-9)/2 so &radic;((10-9)/2)<sup>2</sup> &radic;(1/2)<sup>2</sup> &radic;(1/4) (1/2) LHS=RHS

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt {a^2}\ne a $.  You should never have been taught that it does.

Instead $\sqrt {a^2}=|a| $ .

So....

$(4-9/2)^2=(5-9/2)^2$

$\sqrt {(4-9/2)^2}=\sqrt {(5-9/2)^2}$

$|4-9/2|=|5-9/2|$

$4 - 9/2 = \pm 5 \mp 9/2$

$4 = 5$ or $4 = -5 +2* 9/2=-5+9$

$4-4=5-4$ or $4-4 =-5-4+9$

$0=1$ or $0 = 0$

Comment: So, I'm simply give the answer:
we cannot root the negative integer,as in question
`&radic;(4-9/2)<sup>2</sup>=&radic;(5-9/2)<sup>2</sup>`
explaination:
LHS:4-9/2=(8-9)/2
so &radic;((8-9)/2)<sup>2</sup>
&radic;(-1/2)<sup>2</sup>
&radic;(1/4)
(1/2)
RHS:5-9/2=(10-9)/2
so &radic;((10-9)/2)<sup>2</sup>
&radic;(1/2)<sup>2</sup>
&radic;(1/4)
(1/2)
LHS=RHS

Comment: Not quite.  $(5-9/2)^2 = 1/4$ and $(4-9/2)^2 = 1/4$ and that's fine.  But if $a^2 = b^2$ that does NOT mean $a = b$.  The problem $x^2 = 25$ has *two* answers.  $x = 5$ is one answer but $x = -5$ is another.  If $c > 0$ then there is one *positive* number $r$ so that $r^2 = c$ and there is one *negative* number that is equal to $-r$ so that $(-r)^2 = c$.  So $a^2 = b^2$ does not mean $a = b$ but it means $|a| = |b|$ but either a or b could be positive or negative.  So you have $(4-9/2)^2 = (5-9/2)^2$ which is fine  But 4 - 9/2 < 0 while 5 - 9/2 > 0. so... to be continued...

Comment: ... continued.... and you have $(4-9/2)^2 = (5-9/2)^2$ which is fine (they both equal $1/4$).  And you have $\sqrt{(4- 9/2)^2} = \sqrt{5-9/2)^2}$ which is *also* fine (they both equal $1/2$).  But you have $\sqrt{(4-9/2)^2} = 4-9/2 = - 1/2$ which is *NOT* fine.  This isn't true.  $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5 \ne -5$.  $\sqrt{a^2} \ne a$--- you should never have learned that.  $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$.  $|a| = 0$ if $a \ge 0$ but $|a| = -a$ if $a \le 0$.  So you can conclude $|4- 9/2| = |5-9/2|$ which is fine.  They both equal 1/2.