# Math books that discuss incorrect theorems

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, fake-proofs

A previous teacher of mine had a book that had proofs to well known mathematical formulas/ideas but they were either proved incorrectly or were proved to be something else (i.e. if $x=y$ but we prove $x=2y$ using false assumptions that cleverly look right).

I would like to know books that deal with such kinds of problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I had this book called “Magnificient Mistakes in Mathematics” written by Posamentier and Lehmann and I should say that I absolutely loved it. Gave a great insight into the mistakes that even famous mathematicians did in their work. A book review is given [here](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/books/magnificent-mistakes-in-mathematics-by-alfred-s-posamentier-and-ingmar-lehmann/2007339.article#survey-answer).

Why go so far? Take our own [MSE collection of fake proofs!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection)

Enjoy!

Comment: Also see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disproved_mathematical_ideas

Comment: @frog0101 You can accept my answer if it helped you.