# Writing a Fake Proof for Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fake-proofs

mathematics community!

I'm teaching a course in Real Analysis soon, and one thing I wanted to include were a few "fake proofs" for my students to evaluate. The research I've done hasn't turned up any fake-proofs regarding continuity.

So I'll put it out to you: do any of you have a favorite "proof" involving continuity or a sequential criterion with a flaw in it that could potentially stump some people?

Comment: "All horses are the same color" is a classic.

Comment: you may find some good examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection)

Comment: Limit of a pointwise convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @DougM : In 1997 I took a real analysis class and one of the homework problems was to evaluate the fake induction proof of the statement "All horses are brown."  I had no idea it was a famous problem until your comment above. I am amazed that in 21 years the problem has not changed from "horses" to something else, like Pokemon characters!

Comment: I never heard it as horses until about five years ago.  It was always marbles in a bag.  And that was 38 years ago.

Comment: @fleablood : It sounds like you have lost your marbles.

Comment: Well, if the proof works on my marbles, then I didn't have very many to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I have a favorite one, but I find this one nice:

The proof of the following statement has a flaw. Identify the false statement in the proof, and give an example to show that it is false:

Every bounded continuous real-valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ attains its maximum.

*Proof.* Let $M=\sup\{f(x) \colon x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and let $x^*, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to x^*$ and $f(x_n) \to M$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_n) \to f(x^*)$, which implies $f(x^*)=M$. Hence, $x^*$ is where $f$ attains its maximum.

In general, a nice place for ideas or even outright problems might be [Counterexamples in Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857650).

Comment: Nice one.  This is almost like "proof by assuming the conclusion."

Comment: I´m not sure if I got it, but the only step that looks ilegal to me is assuming there is a sequence such that $x_n \to x^*$ and $f(x_n) \to M$. My counterexample would be $\arctan$...

Comment: @dude3221 The error lies precisely there. Essentially, you've prevented $x_n$ from converging to $x^*$ by 'pushing' $x^*$ out to $\infty$. Your example of $\arctan \theta$ works just fine, as would any function (meeting the theorem conditions) whose image has a horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 3):

This does not involve continuity, but it is a "false proof" that involves basic concepts.  I made this up as a problem set question when I first taught linear algebra.

---

What is *incorrect* about the following chain of reasoning?

We have this problem:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
                          1  & -2 \\
                             3  & 2 \\
                             1 & -4 
                            \end{array}
                                 \right]    \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                          x \\
                             y
                            \end{array}
                                 \right]      =   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                          -1 \\
                             5 \\
                             1 
                            \end{array}
                                 \right]    $$

Hence: 
              $$   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
                      2 & 6 & 2 \\
                       -3 & 1 & 0 
                        \end{array}
                             \right]                \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
                      1  & -2 \\
                         3  & 2 \\
                         1 & -4 
                        \end{array}
                             \right]    \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                      x \\
                         y
                        \end{array}
                             \right]      =       \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
                      2 & 6 & 2 \\
                        -3 & 1 & 0 
                        \end{array}
                             \right]  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                      -1 \\
                         5 \\
                         1 
                        \end{array}
                             \right]   $$

Hence: 
                     $$    \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
                      22 & 0 \\
                        0 & 8 
                        \end{array}
                             \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                      x \\
                         y
                        \end{array}\right]       =       \left[ \begin{array}{c}
                      30 \\
                        8 
                        \end{array}
                             \right]   $$

Therefore, the solution is $y = 1$, $x = 30/22$.

Comment: Because the initial system had a contradiction, right ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas : Yep.   It is actually a correct proof of the (true)  statement “If $(x,y)$ satisfies that first equation, then $(x,y)$ must be $(30/22, 1)$.” Of course, there is no $(x,y)$ that satisfies that first equation, so the “then” part is irrelevant!

Comment: Thank for the response; It is indeed a nice "false proof".