# A Collection of Bogus Proofs

Tags: soft-question, big-list, fake-proofs

Hello M.S.E. people,
This question is just for fun, don't take it seriously :). We have all encountered Bogus Proofs, which seem logical and reasonable, but they prove some claims which are completely wrong and unreasonable. Lets collect a list of very convincing, yet Bogus Proofs. Let me show one down below;
[image: Cool Animation]

I understand this isn't really a 'question', but its just a fun post to make M.S.E. more interesting and fun.

Comment: Here is [a related posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265853/too-simple-to-be-true).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348198/best-fake-proofs-a-m-se-april-fools-day-collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a classic one;
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^2\right)
&=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{x\text{ times}}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)+\cdots+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)}_{x\text{ times}}\\
&=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{x\text{ times}}\\
&=x.
\end{align*}

But since $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^2\right)=2x,$ we have;
\begin{align*}
2x &=x\\
\implies 2 &=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: This one is oddly satisfying until you see $2=1$ :).

Comment: Where's the mistake for positive $x$?

Comment: Here in the derivative, $x$ is an unfixed variable, while when we say "$x$ times", we are fixing it and taking it as a constant. That too, it would have to be an integral constant for "$x$ times".

Comment: It would be fine if we applied the multivariate chain rule :) The following technically works out to the right answer of $2x$: $$\underbrace{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)+\cdots+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)}_{x\text{ times}} + \underbrace{x + x + \dots + x}_{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x) \text{ times}}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Theorem.** Every horse has the same color.

**Proof.** Let's show by induction on $n$ that every horse in a set with $n$ horses have the same color.

- If $n=1$, the statement is trivially true.
- If the statement is true for $n$, consider a set of $n+1$ horses. If we remove one of the horses from the set, the remaining ones should all have the same color.
  [image]

Now we can add the removed horse back again in the set and remove some other random horse.
[image]

Again we have a set of $n$ horses, so they all should have the same color. In particular, the first removed horse have the same color as the previous, concluding our proof. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

$A=B=1$

$A=B$

$A^2=AB$

$A^2-B^2=AB-B^2$

$(A+B)(A-B)=B(A-B)$

$A+B=B$

$1+1=1$

$2=1$

(The fallacy of dividing by zero in moving from the fifth line to the sixth line)

Answer (score 2):

$-20=-20$

$25-45=16-36$

$5^2-(5×9)=4^2-(4×9)$

$5^2-(5×9)+\frac{81}{4}=4^2-(4×9)+\frac{81}{4}$

$(5-\frac{9}{2})^2=(4-\frac{9}{2})^2$

$5-\frac{9}{2}=4-\frac{9}{2}$

$5=4$

(The fallacy in moving from the fifth line to the sixth line, since when writing the square root of the square of a negative number, the sign under the root must be reversed)

Answer (score 2):

$\pi=4$

[image]

---

$\pi=\infty$

[image]

(Squiggly lines can be used to approximate area only, not to approximate perimeter)

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{-1}=(-1)^\frac{1}{2}$

$=(-1)^\frac{2}{4}$

$=((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{4}$

$=1^\frac{1}{4}$

$=1$

The error occurs at the end, as we neglected the quadruple roots of $1$ , which are $1$ , $-1$ , $i$ , $-i$ , and contented ourselves with With only one root.

Comment: Even with your resolution there's still a fallacy: you get that $\sqrt{-1}=1^{1/4}=\pm 1,\pm i$, but $\sqrt{-1}$ is only $\pm i$.